# Calculate Minimum by Ignoring NA for Non-Adjacent Cells in MS Excel

Tags: excel, min

I have data (example *as below*) where I want to find a **Minimum** value for ***L*** and ***R*** but ignoring *NA*.

I've tried to refer to https://superuser.com/questions/862279/minimum-of-non-zero-non-adjacent-cells-in-ms-excel and other functions, but it does not working.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use array formula:

if `N/A` is error value

```
{=MIN(IFERROR(IF($A$2:$J$2=K$2,$A3:$J3,""),""))}
```

if `N/A` is string just remove `IFERROR` function

```
{=MIN(IF($A$2:$J$2=K$2,$A3:$J3,""))}
```

Array formula after editing is confirmed by pressing `ctrl` + `shift` + `enter`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

to find just values of L

```
=IF(AND(A11="L",NOT(A13="N/A")),A13)
```

[image]

and to find just values of R

```
=IF(AND(A11="R",NOT(A13="N/A")),A13)
```

[image]

and then find Minimum of them

[image]